# Did Future John experience the events of Terminator 2?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

It is clear that the events of *The Terminator* film happened as part of the 2029 future timeline shown in the film as John seemed to have foreknowledge on certain events such as Skynet's secret weapon (the Time Displacement Equipment) as well as the information Sarah gave him.

Saying that, did *Terminator 2: Judgement Day* also happen, or does the future timeline shown in the film only connect to the first film?

Answer (score 10):

There are at least two ways to interpret the question.

- **Has the John Connor that we see in 2029 at the beginning of *Terminator: Genisys* experienced the events of *Terminator 2* ?**
- **Does the future timeline shown in *Genisys* eventually evolve into the *Terminator 2* timeline, or does it only connect to the timeline of the first *Terminator* film?**

These are different questions, and I will try to answer them both.

**Answer to "Question #1":**

## The events of *Terminator 2* were almost certainly *not* experienced by the John Connor that we meet at the beginning of *Genisys*.

In *Terminator 2*, John and Sarah Connor destroy the Skynet project in its infancy and dispose of anything that can lead to its creation.  This happened in 1995.

The John Connor at the beginning of *Genisys* is a product of the events of *The Terminator* — literally, Kyle Reese mating with Sarah Connor — and eventually becomes a commander in the war against the machines.  **The key piece of information is that, in this timeline, Skynet did become active in 1997.**  The date on which Judgement Day had occurred is confirmed at the very beginning of *Genisys* by Kyle Reese' voiceover.

If *T2* had occurred in this timeline, meaning that the Skynet project had been destroyed in 1995, it is very unlikely that Cyberdyne or any other company or agency could have had Skynet fully developed and running in 1997.

Although *T3* may no longer be [canon](http://comicbook.com/2015/06/08/james-cameron-says-terminator-genisys-is-the-real-third-terminat/) necessarily, we see in that film that it took **nine years** for Skynet to become operational and self-aware after the setback of *T2*.

Note that the 2029 events at the beginning of *Genisys* **do not require** anything that John would have learned or experienced in *T2*.  The privileged information he has is that:

- Kyle Reese is his father
- the machines will create a "temporal displacement device" as a failsafe; when the war begins to go badly for them in 2029, they will use it to send a Terminator back to 1984 to murder John's mother Sarah
- John will use the device to send Kyle Reese back to save her

These are things that he would have learned from Sarah from *T1* alone.  This knowledge is why at the start of *Genisys*,

> in a final campaign to end the war, John leads a separate mission from the Colorado mission.  The Colorado mission is intended to take out Skynet itself, while John's mission is to take out the temporal displacement device so that the machines cannot use it when it becomes clear that Skynet will not be able to repel the human forces in Colorado.

But despite their best efforts, events play out just as in the "history of the future" he has been taught, for John and his troops

> find the temporal displacement device a few seconds too late, by which time the machines have sent the T-800 back in time to 1984.

At this point,

> Kyle Reese volunteers to go back in time to stop the T-800.  John picks Kyle over the other volunteers because he knows Kyle's destiny.  (It is made absolutely clear later in the film that John knows that Kyle is his father and that he had deliberately withheld that information from Kyle in case events played out like this and someone had to be sent back in time.  John wanted to ensure that Kyle would father Sarah's child, and so he withheld information from Kyle that might influence his decision-making and the subsequent course of events.)

Absolutely none of this requires anything that John Connor learned or experienced in *T2*.  Combined with the fact that **Judgement Day still occurred *on-time* in 1997**, we can fairly safely assume that the John Connor of *Genisys* had experienced *T1* but did not experience *T2*.

**Answer to "Question #2":**

## Whether or not the events of *Terminator 2* have occurred in John Connor's life by the start of *Genisys*, the events of *Terminator 2* will not follow on from the 2029 events that we see.

In *Genisys*, shortly after

> Kyle Reese steps into the machine to follow the T-800 back to 1984, a human soldier by the name of "Alex" grabs John's face.  Kyle watches in horror from inside the temporal displacement device as John's face starts to come apart.

It turns out that

> "Alex" is not a human at all, but rather Skynet itself in a humanoid form, known as the T-5000.  As we see later in the film, the T-5000 infected John with a nanovirus — the T-3000 — which transforms John into a human-machine hybrid that has all of John's memories and skills but which is sympathetic to Skynet's cause.

So even if the machines were to have sent a T-1000 to 1995 to assassinate 10-year-old John Connor, thereby "initiating" the *T2* timeline,

> the T-1000 would not find John Connor in 1995, because Kyle Reese and Sarah Connor left 1984 together using a homemade version of the temporal displacement device, in order to prevent Skynet from proliferating as the Genisys operating system in 2017.  If they were to have a child, it would be after 2017, and so John Connor would no longer be alive in 1995.

Also,

> the future John's new loyalties mean he would not reprogram a "guardian" T-800 to follow the T-1000 back to 1995.

So, in other words, the timeline of *T2* is completely eradicated because of

> the T-5000's interference.

Interestingly, this [interview](http://www.mandatory.com/culture/873983-exclusive-terminator-genisys-screenwriters-reveal-big-secret) reveals that

> the T-5000 is *not* the Skynet that was destroyed in Colorado, but rather a Skynet from an entirely different timeline or universe that has developed the ability to jump between parallel universes.  The appearance of this new Skynet is what prevents the usual *T1* / *T2* sequence of timelines from occurring as we know them.

Thanks to @Hypnosifl for the interview link!

Comment: Well explained. If anyone thinks T series timeline is hard to understand, check the Legacy of Kane series one. :D

Comment: It's worth mentioning that we the audience see the time machine used, and it's only used once by Skynet, to send T1's T800 Terminator back in time.  We do not see Skynet send back T2's T1000, so the events that precipitated *Terminator 2* are not what we see in *Genisys*.

Comment: Good answer, but I think it would be worth adding the info revealed in [this interview](http://www.craveonline.com/entertainment/film/interviews/873983-exclusive-terminator-genisys-screenwriters-reveal-big-secret): the Skynet-in-human form who we see in the movie is supposed to be a Skynet from an entirely different timeline/universe, who had learned how to hop between timelines, so presumably he was altering this timeline at the moment he appeared, causing it to diverge from the 2029 of T2 where Skynet would have sent a T-1000 to 1995 and John would have sent a T-800 to stop it.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : I hadn't come across that interview --- great find!  When I have a chance later, I'll weave that into the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. BTW, thinking about this, if you go with the diverging-timelines theory then it seems like an open question whether the John Connor shown in the 2029 of T2 would remember meeting a T-800 which stopped a T-1000 in his own version of 1995; it's quite possible that in his own past, some version of a T-800 and Kyle Reese did appear in 1984, but there were no terminators sent to 1995, because in the "previous" timeline (perhaps the 2029 seen in T1) Skynet only managed to send one Terminator back.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : That's basically the upshot of my answer.  If John experienced a T-800 stopping a T-1000 in 1995, then he also would have partook in the subsequent destruction of the Skynet project in 1995 and the melting down of all of the remaining cybernetic components that were present at that time.  This means that Judgement Day could not have happened "on time" in 1997 (if *T3* is any indication).  However, Kyle Reese states at the beginning of *Genisys* that Judgement Day happened on 29 Aug 1997, and so we can presume that the events of *T2* could not have happened in that timeline...

Comment: ...However, the knowledge he has about his true father and about the existence of the temporal displacement device means that his mother would have experienced *T1* in 1984 and relayed this information to him.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Having now read the interview and having thought about it, I'm not sure the interference of the T-5000 (that's Skynet in human form) affects the answer.  Its interference certainly means that a T-1000 is unlikely to be sent back to 1995 from this 2029 (and the infection of John with the T-3000 nanovirus means that John certainly wouldn't sent a T-800 to stop it), but the question is whether John had *already* experienced *T2* or not (for which I believe the answer is "no", for the reasons outlined above).

Comment: True, the things you mentioned are enough to deduce the John in the movie hadn't experienced the events of T2. But I also sort of interpreted "or does the future timeline shown in the film only connect to the first film?" to be asking about whether Genisys was simply removing T2 from its own "canon". In that case, I'd say you don't have pretend T2 doesn't exist, but just to imagine there were (at least) two timelines resulting from the events of T1, an "original" future of T1 where Skynet sends back the T-1000, and an altered future that diverges from that future timeline due to the T-5000.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : That's definitely one way to interpret the question.  In that case, the information from the interview about the T-5000 would certainly apply.  I'll update the answer later today to reflect that interpretation of the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

It seems that because the original T1 Terminator was destroyed in T:G, T2 was averted.

Comment: I think the question is asking whether the John Connor we meet at the very beginning of *Genisys* had experienced *T2* (before the film shifts to 1984).  In other words, how did the John Connor at the very beginning know to storm the machines' storage facility and look for the the temporal displacement device?

Comment: Also, just because the original *T1* Terminator was basically destroyed on arrival in *T:G*, this doesn't necessarily nullify *T2*. Remember, the T-1000 in *T2* was sent to 1995 *because* the original Terminator failed in 1984. It still fails in *Genisys*, just much more quickly. (This time around, if a T-1000 were sent to 1995, it simply wouldn't find its intended target, because of other things that transpire in *Genisys*. The point is, the destruction of the *T1* Terminator alone is not really the source of the divergent timeline.)